# inotify and rsync on large number of files

Tags: rsync, inotify

I am using inotify to watch a directory and sync files between servers using rsync. Syncing works perfectly, and memory usage is mostly not an issue. However, recently a large number of files were added (350k) and this has impacted performance, specifically on CPU. Now when rsync runs, CPU usage spikes to 90%/100% and rsync takes long to complete, there are 650k files being watched/synced.

Is there any way to speed up rsync and only rsync the directory that has been changed? Or alternatively to set up multiple inotifywaits on separate directories. Script being used is below.

UPDATE: I have added the --update flag and usage seems mostly unchanged

```
#! /bin/bash

EVENTS="CREATE,DELETE,MODIFY,MOVED_FROM,MOVED_TO"

inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%:e %f' /var/www/ --exclude '/var/www/.*cache.*' | (
WAITING="";
while true; do
    LINE="";
    read -t 1 LINE;
    if test -z "$LINE"; then
        if test ! -z "$WAITING"; then
                echo "CHANGE";
                WAITING="";
                rsync --update -alvzr --exclude '*cache*' --exclude '*.git*' /var/www/* root@secondwebserver:/var/www/
        fi;
    else
        WAITING=1;
    fi;
done)
```

Comment: I think I would try splitting this into 2 pieces to determine where the poor performance is actually coming from. If you run just the `inotify` piece by itself, w/o the `rsync` does the poor performance continue, or are you positive the root cause is `rsync`?

Comment: Pretty sure it's the rsync. When I watch `top` that's what causes the increase in CPU, running as a system process.

Comment: Hm both scripts ignore the actual events. So this triggers a full rsync run. It would maybe be good to actually trigger rsync on partial trees. Or maybe add a time-limit - or collect multiple events in short time together and only kick off a new rsync at the end of a burst.

Comment: This script seems to run full `rsync` every time a single file has been changed. If/when your inotifywait returns multiple lines, the whole `rsync` will be run equally many times. You either need to collect list of modified files and sync that list as soon as possible (basically start sync on first modified file and start collecting list of new files in paraller with the sync, re-sync with the new list after the first sync is ready and start collecting another list for the time sync is going). Or just run `unison` instead.

Comment: @kyleredon, you might remove `MODIFY` event, since it will be generated A LOT when a large file is being downloaded/created. Also, if you act/sync on `MODIFY` event, without waiting for `CLOSE_WRITE` event, you might sync an incomplete file. In essence, you only need to trigger sync on these events: `CLOSE_WRITE, MOVED_TO, MOVED_FROM, DELETE`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the server has a slow processor avoid checksums and compression with rsync. 
I would remove ht "-z" option in the rsync command.

```
rsync --update -alvr --exclude '*cache*' --exclude '*.git*' /var/www/* root@secondwebserver:/var/www/
```

Note that it will not avoid rsync to  compare the 650k files.
You could rsync subdirectories of /var/www one by one to reduce the number of files checked at one time.

Comment: I ended up removing the compression option (z) and upping the WAITING var to 10 (seconds). This seems to have helped, rsync still spikes CPU load but it is shorter lived. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for posting your answer - it really helped me. I think you can simplify the loop:

```sh
EVENTS="CREATE,DELETE,MODIFY,MOVED_FROM,MOVED_TO"

sync() {
  rsync --update -alvzr --exclude '*cache*' --exclude '*.git*' /var/www/* root@secondwebserver:/var/www/

}
watch() {
  inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%:e %f' /var/www/ --exclude '/var/www/.*cache.*' 
}


watch | (
while true ; do
  read -t 1 LINE && sync
done
)
```

You may need to adjust that slightly but the gist should be clear. I'm using a variant with Amazon's AWS s3 sync, so I may have substituted your rsync command in incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You might check this tool [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)

I'm using dockerized version from [this repo](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/syncthing/)

I have 411k files to sync using this tool, I had some issues regarding file names encoding for some files named in arabic

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run -d --rm \
  --name=syncthing \
  -e PUID=1000 \
  -e PGID=1000 \
  -e TZ=Asia/Jordan \
  -e UMASK_SET=022 \
  -p 8384:8384 \
  -p 22000:22000 \
  -p 21027:21027/udp \
  -v "$(pwd)/config:/config" \
  -v "path_to_sync:/config/Sync" \
  --net host \
  linuxserver/syncthing
```

Note: use GUI to configure