# How to run this rsyncs as deamon (trigger only when a file has changed)

Tags: rsync

I have multiple folders that I rsync now with cron like in this example.

```
rsync -aq source1/  user1@machine1:/some/destination1
rsync -aq source2/  user2@machine2:/some/destination2
... and so on
```

Everything is running fine, but I have a lot of crontabs as root, and most of the time nothing changes, and I am just blocking processor.

I would like to start the rsync processes only when a file somewhere on source has changed.

So I have read the documentation of the rsync.conf file, but I did not understand how this works.
My rsync.conf file right now looks like this :

```
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid

&merge /etc/rsyncd.d
&include /etc/rsyncd.d
```

and the /etc/rsyncd.d folder is empty.

how do I need to write the config in order that the rsync runs as daemon and just syncs when a file has changed. I an aware that the -a option is just sending the differences, and just when something changed, I am not sure if I save processor if the deamon is running this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rsync daemon doesn't watch the filesystem, it's just a listener.  It waits for other rsync jobs to start and connect for moving files.

For your purpose you want something to watch for changes (a la inotify) and use that info to start an rsync process.  These other answers might be good starting points.

[inotify and rsync on large number of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103858/inotify-and-rsync-on-large-number-of-files)

https://serverfault.com/questions/688656/how-do-correctly-sync-millions-of-files-with-rsync-and-inotify